# Next without For - Error

Tags: excel, for-loop, vba

Stupid question: This code isn't compiling correctly, and I can't find a solution on any of the other "Next without For" questions.  I have a feeling I'm just missing something stupid.  Here's the relevant code:

```
 For Each Cell In CHWAssigned
    If Cell = "" Then
        If Cell.Row Mod 3 = 0 Then
            Cell.Value = "DM"
        ElseIf Cell.Row Mod 3 = 1 Then
            Cell.Value = "CWS"
        ElseIf Cell.Row Mod 3 = 2 Then
            Cell.Value = "CF"
    Else
    End If
Next Cell
```

I think I've closed all of the If statements, but there must be one in there that's open.  Thanks for taking the time to address something so simple.

Comment: You have two Ifs but only one End If ...

Comment: you haven't closed the last `ElseIf`, control falls to an `Else` which is within a parent `If` block.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  Just noticed it right when you commented

Answer (score 1):

You are missing and End if, your code should work now. You don't need to specify  `Cell` in the `Next` statement. Also you can use `Case` instead of `ElseIf`.

```
For Each Cell In CHWAssigned
   If Cell = "" Then
       If Cell.Row Mod 3 = 0 Then
          Cell.Value = "DM"
       ElseIf Cell.Row Mod 3 = 1 Then
          Cell.Value = "CWS"
       ElseIf Cell.Row Mod 3 = 2 Then
          Cell.Value = "CF"
       End If
    End If
Next
```

Hope it helps.